# Titanium - How to display Month-Date-Year Only

Tags: android, date, titanium, titanium-mobile

I'm trying to create a label that allows user to select a date in Titanium.  My code compiles, but it displays both the date and time when I ask for date only (note: I do my testing with an Android emulator).  Can someone take a look at my code and give me a hint on how to solve this issue? Your help is greatly appreciated!

```
//create a new window
var addWin = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
    title: "Add New Entry",
    backgroundColor: '#ffffff'
});

//header
//addWin.add(Inova.ui.createHeaderView());  //error

//body
var body = Titanium.UI.createView({
    backgroundColor:'#fff', 
    height: 800,
    layout: 'vertical'
});

//Addin a label to the body
body.add(Titanium.UI.createLabel({
    text: 'New Travel Entry',
    top: 10,
    color: '#008000',
    textAlign: 'center',
    font: {fontSize:20},
    width:'auto',      //Define width of the label
    height:'auto'      //Define height of the label
}));

var dateLabel = Titanium.UI.createTextField({
    text: 'Date: ',
    hintText:'Click here to select a date',
    font: {fontSize: 20},
    top:20,
    left:10,
    width:'auto',
    height: 'auto',
    color: '#336699',
    editable:false,
    borderStyle:Ti.UI.INPUT_BORDERSTYLE_ROUNDED
});

var dateUpdated = false;

dateLabel.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    var picker = Titanium.UI.createPicker({
        type: Titanium.UI.PICKER_TYPE_DATE,
        minDate: new Date(2012,1,1),
        maxDate: new Date(2014,12,30),
        value: new Date(2013,12,2)
    });

    picker.showDatePickerDialog({
        value: new Date(2012,12,2),
        callback: function(e)
        {
            if (e.cancel)
            {
                Titanium.API.info('User canceled dialog');
            } else 
            {
                Titanium.API.info ('USer selected date: ' + e.value);
                dateLabel.value = e.value;
                dateLabel.text = (e.value.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + e.value.getDate() + '/' + e.value.getFullYear(),
                dateUpdated = true;
            }
        }
    });
});

body.add(dateLabel);


addWin.add(body);
addWin.open();
```

Comment: Your code looks fine, I only see what you mean from this line: `Titanium.API.info ('USer selected date: ' + e.value);`
 Your label has the correct value `dateLabel.text = (e.value.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + e.value.getDate() + '/' + e.value.getFullYear()`. Are you sure that this is the problem you have?

Comment: @kabomi: Yes, the result I keep getting is like "Sun Feb 02 14:08:28 PST 2013". I want to show something like "Feb 02 2013". Do you have any suggestion on how I can change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your problem starts here:

```
var dateLabel = Titanium.UI.createTextField({
    text: 'Date: ',
```

You are not defining a `Label` but a `TextField`. I would change its name to dateField or dateTextField for clarity.

A TextField doesn't have a text property, it has a value property.

You are setting `dateLabel.value  = e.value;` and that's why you are seeing values that the one you mentioned `Sun Feb 02 14:08:28 PST 2013`. That fragment should change to:

```
...

var dateUpdated = false;

dateLabel.addEventListener('click', function(e){

...
        } else 
        {
            Titanium.API.info ('USer selected date: ' + e.value);
            dateLabel.value =  e.value.toDateString().slice(4);
            dateUpdated = true;
        }
...
```

This way, dateLabel.value will produce something like "Dec 02 2013"